# Why doesn't onclick event affect CSS3 animation-duration property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a small game, where an element bounces from the top to the bottom of its parent element, and vice versa. Once the user clicks the element, the speed increases [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S2dTE/).

I am using the following CSS properties to set values (I have omitted the prefixes):

```
#ball {
    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;       
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    100% {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        margin-top: 420px;
    }
}
```

The JavaScript code I am using to change the duration of the animation:

```
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');

ball.onclick = function() {
    ball.style.WebkitAnimationDuration = '100ms';
    ball.style.MozAnimationDuration = '100ms';
    ball.style.OAnimationDuration = '100ms';
    ball.style.animationDuration = '100ms';
};
```

My question is as follows: Why does the animation-duration not change?

Comment: What do you mean not change? I checked on Mac FF latest and when I click the span, the ball is bouncing rapidly

Comment: I found the problem ball.style.animationDuration, should have had the a in animation capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
ball.style.animationDuration = '100ms';
```

It should be like so:

```
ball.style.AnimationDuration = '100ms';
```